# Play Framework: How do I validate for empty text box

Tags: java, playframework-2.0

I am working on Play Framework 2 for Java and I was trying to validate the text box in my form so I used `@Required`, It was working fine if we are not entering anything inside the text box but when we are typing `spaces` on text box then it fails. In short we can say its not trimming the text box value. I also tried `@NotNull` but it was also not working any more. Please help to out of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Introduce an extra validation annotation that checks whether the input matches a non-whitespace regular expression:

```
@Required
@Pattern("[\\S]+")
public String name;
```

- `\s` is a shorthand character class that matches a whitespace character
- `\S` is the negated version of this that matches a non-whitespace character
- `+` indicates we need at least one non-whitespace character for a match
- Finally, the backslash needs escaping in Java syntax.

Comment: Its showing `constraint.pattern` in all time, If I typed any value inside textbox, at this moment its showing validation error.

Comment: Whoops, missed out a ``+`` operator from my regex. Give this a go

Comment: Now Its working @avik, thanks for the solution. +1 for detail. but its showing validation error text as `constraint.pattern`, can you please tell me how do I change the validation message.

Comment: Assuming you're using your own ``messages`` file(s), you can either (1) Add the ``constraint.pattern`` key to your message file or (2) set the ``message`` attribute on the ``@Pattern`` annotation to a custom key that you then have to put into your message file.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to prevent users from entering only white spaces into the text field, you can use:

```
    @Constraints.Required
    @Formats.NonEmpty
    public String name;
```

The accepted solution will not validate if you have white spaces in between your words. If that's what you want, then it's ok.